# Old Moto Droid w/ 2.2 developer options?

Tags: android, hardware, motorola

I'd like to push what I'm working on to my old Motorola Droid with 2.2 froyo, but I cannot find anywhere the developer options or a way to unlock them if they are hidden.

Is there a different method to get Eclipse to see the phone with this old hardware?

Comment: Look under Applications->Development.